# Why the echo failed?

Tags: bash

I want to create many new bash scripts through this bash. Here is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
# create bash shell automatically
for file in "$*"
do
    if [ ! -e "$file" ]
    then
        touch $file
        chmod u+x $file
        echo "#!/bin/bash" >> $file
        echo "# " >> $file
        echo "create success"
    fi
done
if [ $# \> 1 ]
then
    echo "$# shell files are created!"
else
    echo "$# shell is created!"
fi
```

When I run this script like this:

```
./create_shell test1 test2 test3
```

the terminal said:

```
"line9:ambiguous redirect"
"line10:ambiguous redirect"
```

What does that mean?

Comment: The `[ $# \> 1 ]` is not a valid test.  With `[`, you use `-gt` to do numeric 'greater than' comparison.  Whether that degenerates to an ambiguous redirect is less clear; line 9 is somewhat before that one.  Are you sure all the spacing in your code is exactly as shown in the question?

Comment: Yes.I checked many times

Comment: Use `$@` instead of `$*`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: No, `[ $# \> 1 ]` is valid in `bash`. It's string comparison operator inside `[...]`. Here `>` was escaped to prevent the shell from seeing it as redirection operator,

Comment: Given that you're using `"$*"`, the value in `file` is `test1 test2 test3`.  When you expand that with `echo "xxxx" >> $file` without quotes, Bash gets upset.  You can demonstrate by running with a single argument: things work fine then.  If you quoted the variable: `echo "xxx" >> "$file"`, it would be OK.  If you used `"$@"` you would be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from the use of `$*`, whether you quote or unquote it. The correct way to iterate through positional parameter is using `"$@"`, notice the double quote.

```
for file in "$@"; do
  : ...
done
```

or even POSIXly:

```
for file do
  : ...
done
```

You got the error message from `bash`, because `bash` see the content of `$file` was not expanded to one word, it was expanded to three separated words `test1`, `test2`, `test3`. Try:

```
a='1 2 3'
echo 1 >> $a
```

to see what will happen.

Not to mention that you spoil the sole reason for using `"$@"`. In order for this construct to work, you must also put double quotes around the variables that derive from it, if you don't want the `split+glob` operators to be invoked. [Leaving variables unquote will lead to many security implications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906).

Answer (score -1):

The '$*' is a string not the parameter array. You can do it like this

```
fileArr=($*)
for file in ${fileArr[@]}
do you things
```

Comment: No, the correct solution is to use `"$@"` instead of `"$*"`.

Answer (score -2):

The quotes around "$*" will prevent bash from parsing the passed parameter into individual tokens.  The loop will be executed once with all of the parameters passed (i.e. if you ran `test.sh one two three` then the echo command will try to redirect to "one two three").  Just remove the quotes.

Comment: No, don't remove the quotes, that's precisely the wrong thing to do! This will prevent the script from ever working with file names containing shell metacharacters.